# Push through list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, push, each

I have an each function of li's similar to

```
theList = $('#list li')
total = theList.length;   
  theList.each(function(i){      
   //stuff
    theItems = [];
    theItems.push($(this).animate({opacity:'1'},1111).delay(100).animate({opacity:'.8'}));
})
```

I'm trying to figure out how to isolate each one, perform the animation, and move to the next item.

Right now it just does them all at once.

Bonus: How do I keep this from discarding my CSS hover?

```
#list li:hover { opacity:1; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $theList = $('#list li');
$theList.each(function (index) {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 1111).delay(100 * index).animate({
        opacity: '.8'
    });
});
```

Comment: **`delay(100 * index)`** I would have never thought of this. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway to keep this from discarding my css hover effect? (also opacity)

Comment: Try removing one of the animate in the each loop, but do keep the delay. I am not sure, removing which would look better. So, give it a try...

Comment: Once the jQuery animation takes place it still makes it no longer functional. Guess I'll have to add a jQuery hover effect to keep and have the CSS as a fallback.